# Why doesn't my newly-created docker have a digest?

Tags: docker, hash

I have been following the [Docker tutorial here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockerimages/#/image-digests), and built a test image on my local OSX machine by committing changes to an existing image and tagging it with three different labels:

```
# docker images   
REPOSITORY         TAG      IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
adamatan/sinatra   devel    fccb6b4d21b4   8 minutes ago   469.5 MB
adamatan/sinatra   junk     fccb6b4d21b4   8 minutes ago   469.5 MB
adamatan/sinatra   latest   fccb6b4d21b4   8 minutes ago   469.5 MB
```

However, none of these images has a digest:

```
# docker images --digests adamatan/sinatra
REPOSITORY         TAG      DIGEST   IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
adamatan/sinatra   devel    <none>   fccb6b4d21b4   9 minutes ago   469.5 MB
adamatan/sinatra   junk     <none>   fccb6b4d21b4   9 minutes ago   469.5 MB
adamatan/sinatra   latest   <none>   fccb6b4d21b4   9 minutes ago   469.5 MB
```

Other test images I have created with a Dockerfile do have a digest.

**Why do some images have a digest and some don't? Is it related to the way the images were created (Dockerfile or not)?**

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Firstly, Please keep in mind that a digest could represent a `manifest`, a layer or a combination of them (we normally called that combination an image).

`Manifest` is a new term that introduced with Docker registry V2. Here is a short description fetched from [Docker Registry V2 slides](http://www.slideshare.net/Docker/docker-registry-v2) page21 ~ page23:

> - [Manifest] describes the components of an image in a single object
> - Layers can be fetched immediately, in parallel.

When you get the digests with command `docker images --digests`, here the digest is the SHA256 hash  of image manifest, but image ID is the hash code of the local image JSON configuration (this configuration is different from manifest). In this case, if an image doesn't have an associated manifest, the digest of that image will be "none".

Normally, two scenarios could make an image doesn't have associated manifest:

1. This image has not been pushed to or pulled from a V2 registry.
2. This image has been pulled from a V1 registry.

To generate a manifest, the easiest way is to push the image to a V2 registry (V1 registry will not work). Docker client will generate a manifest locally, then push it with image layers to registry. When you pull the image back, the image will have a manifest.

Once the manifest exists, your image digest should not be "none".

Comment: There's a new 'experimental' `docker manifest` command - but it still doesn't quite do what the user would actually want, ie. generate the manifest locally for an image which is missing one.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is related to how the images were created. Docker can be a real stinker at times.

This may be helpful for you in this case:

- 2016-06-08, windsock.io, [*Explaining Docker Image IDs*](https://windsock.io/explaining-docker-image-ids/)

Comment: It's crazy -  `docker inspect <image>` will print the digest, even though `docker images --digests` prints `<none>`.

Comment: Yea. Not sure what to think of it. Bug? Intentional design? Docker is complex if you think about it. I’d stick my hand on a bug. Will submit to them.

Comment: @EdRandall thank you for this. I was going crazy with an un-related skaffold issue, this has helped a lot.

Comment: FWIW and in contrast to @EdRandall above, I **don't** find `docker inspect` to have a digest if `docker images ---digest` shows `<none>`.  Granted, I'm writing this in 2022, with Docker engine version 20.10.17. Things could have changed, but I clarify this for later readers. More specifically, I find that the `inspect` shows the array `RepoDigests` to be empty when there is no digest, otherwise there's a value.

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing this issue (digest was none).

Reason was when I can the docker image and image was listed in **docker images**.

At this point, I was checking for the digest value using

```
docker images --digest
```

and the digest value comes as `<none>`.

**Resolution:**

Push the image in your docker repository, then image will show the digest value.