# What's the difference between a Docker image's Image ID and its Digest?

Tags: docker, hash, sha256

This has been surprisingly confusing for me. I thought Docker's Image ID is its SHA256 hash. However, apparently the result from `docker image ls --digests` (listed under the column header `DIGEST`) is different from the `IMAGE ID` of that image.

For example

```
$ docker image ls --digests alpine
REPOSITORY  TAG     DIGEST                                                                   IMAGE ID      CREATED      SIZE
alpine      latest  sha256:769fddc7cc2f0a1c35abb2f91432e8beecf83916c421420e6a6da9f8975464b6  055936d39205  2 weeks ago  5.53MB
```

while

```
$ docker image ls --no-trunc
REPOSITORY  TAG     IMAGE ID                                                                 CREATED      SIZE
...                                                                                                       
alpine      latest  sha256:055936d3920576da37aa9bc460d70c5f212028bda1c08c0879aedf03d7a66ea1  2 weeks ago  5.53MB
```

Clearly

- `sha256:055936d3920576da37aa9bc460d70c5f212028bda1c08c0879aedf03d7a66ea1` (IMAGE ID) and
- `sha256:769fddc7cc2f0a1c35abb2f91432e8beecf83916c421420e6a6da9f8975464b6` (DIGEST)
  are not the same value. But why? What's the purpose of having two different `sha256` hashes of the same image. How are they calculated, respectively?

I was confused by this when reading the book *Docker Deep Dive*, and I haven't been able to find a clear answer either in the book or online.

Comment: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811230/why-doesnt-my-newly-created-docker-have-a-digest)

Comment: @michalk Thanks for the comment. It offers a clear explanation. I wonder why this distinction is not mentioned more.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Thanks for michalk's comment. The short answer is:

- The "digest" is a hash of the manifest, introduced in Docker registry v2.
- The image ID is a hash of the local image JSON configuration.

Comment: "manifest" vs "JSON configuration"... you've pushed the question "down". What's the difference between these two?

Comment: if you use `regctl manifest get IMAGE`, you can see that a manifest wraps around a config and some layers. Config also has a bunch of rootfs (layers) objects inside, the sha sums differ (between manifest and config), because manifest's layers are after compression and config's rootfs are before compression. The manifest is newer, so it's somewhat redundant for backwards compat I guess.

Comment: I keep going around in circles on this... "The image digest is the hash of the image index or image manifest JSON document..." OK, so does that uniquely identify this particular image such that a later build with slightly different content will have a different digest? That's the question I wish Google answered more straightforwardly when defining "Digest."