# Difference between docker image ID and Digest ID

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I know that this question is covered by below answer. That **image ID is hash of image json config** & **Digest ID is hash of image manifest**.

[What's the difference between a Docker image's Image ID and its Digest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56364643/whats-the-difference-between-a-docker-images-image-id-and-its-digest)

But I still be confused for it. In which scenario that manifest of a docker image can be different with it's json config?

1. Manifest & json config are different format like (xml & json which can contain same data)
2. Manifest & json contains different information for a docker image.

Whether the different between manifest & json config are below to above 1. Or there are some another different.

Comment: I think it can be helpful for you. <br />
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56364643/whats-the-difference-between-a-docker-images-image-id-and-its-digest#:~:text=The%20short%20answer%20is%3A,the%20local%20image%20JSON%20configuration.

Answer (score 3):

These are different json pieces of metadata, defined in the [OCI image-spec](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec) under `manifest.md` and `config.md`.

To show this with a specific image, here's a copy of the alpine image manifest:

```json
$ regctl manifest get localhost:5000/library/alpine --format body | jq .
{
  "manifests": [
    {
      "digest": "sha256:1304f174557314a7ed9eddb4eab12fed12cb0cd9809e4c28f29af86979a3c870",
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "amd64",
        "os": "linux"
      },
      "size": 528
    },
    {
      "digest": "sha256:5da989a9a3a08357bc7c00bd46c3ed782e1aeefc833e0049e6834ec1dcad8a42",
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "arm",
        "os": "linux",
        "variant": "v6"
      },
      "size": 528
    },
    {
      "digest": "sha256:0c673ee68853a04014c0c623ba5ee21ee700e1d71f7ac1160ddb2e31c6fdbb18",
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "arm",
        "os": "linux",
        "variant": "v7"
      },
      "size": 528
    },
    {
      "digest": "sha256:ed73e2bee79b3428995b16fce4221fc715a849152f364929cdccdc83db5f3d5c",
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "arm64",
        "os": "linux",
        "variant": "v8"
      },
      "size": 528
    },
    {
      "digest": "sha256:1d96e60e5270815238e999aed0ae61d22ac6f5e5f976054b24796d0e0158b39c",
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "386",
        "os": "linux"
      },
      "size": 528
    },
    {
      "digest": "sha256:fa30af02cc8c339dd7ffecb0703cd4a3db175e56875c413464c5ba46821253a8",
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "ppc64le",
        "os": "linux"
      },
      "size": 528
    },
    {
      "digest": "sha256:c2046a6c3d2db4f75bfb8062607cc8ff47896f2d683b7f18fe6b6cf368af3c60",
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "s390x",
        "os": "linux"
      },
      "size": 528
    }
  ],
  "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json",
  "schemaVersion": 2
}
```

That manifest is actually a manifest list, similar to the OCI Index which contains multiple manifests, in this case for a multi-platform image. Picking out the first platform, here's the manifest for the linux/amd64 platform:

```json
$ regctl manifest get \
  localhost:5000/library/alpine@sha256:1304f174557314a7ed9eddb4eab12fed12cb0cd9809e4c28f29af86979a3c870 \
  --format body | jq .
{
  "schemaVersion": 2,
  "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
  "config": {
    "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json",
    "size": 1470,
    "digest": "sha256:9c6f0724472873bb50a2ae67a9e7adcb57673a183cea8b06eb778dca859181b5"
  },
  "layers": [
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
      "size": 2806054,
      "digest": "sha256:213ec9aee27d8be045c6a92b7eac22c9a64b44558193775a1a7f626352392b49"
    }
  ]
}
```

That manifest contains descriptors to the image config and a list of layers (in this case a single layer). Pulling the config blob shows the image config and history that you may recognize from inspecting images in docker:

```json
$ regctl blob get localhost:5000/library/alpine \
  sha256:9c6f0724472873bb50a2ae67a9e7adcb57673a183cea8b06eb778dca859181b5 \
  | jq .
{
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "config": {
    "Hostname": "",
    "Domainname": "",
    "User": "",
    "AttachStdin": false,
    "AttachStdout": false,
    "AttachStderr": false,
    "Tty": false,
    "OpenStdin": false,
    "StdinOnce": false,
    "Env": [
      "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    ],
    "Cmd": [
      "/bin/sh"
    ],
    "Image": "sha256:c0261ca8a4a79627f3e658c0c2b1e3166f56713a58e1411b1e3ab1e378962e75",
    "Volumes": null,
    "WorkingDir": "",
    "Entrypoint": null,
    "OnBuild": null,
    "Labels": null
  },
  "container": "0c4b20968eb1d804460f8612bc52be4f5a8e65eb14190b5ae30fec94d2fb4f50",
  "container_config": {
    "Hostname": "0c4b20968eb1",
    "Domainname": "",
    "User": "",
    "AttachStdin": false,
    "AttachStdout": false,
    "AttachStderr": false,
    "Tty": false,
    "OpenStdin": false,
    "StdinOnce": false,
    "Env": [
      "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    ],
    "Cmd": [
      "/bin/sh",
      "-c",
      "#(nop) ",
      "CMD [\"/bin/sh\"]"
    ],
    "Image": "sha256:c0261ca8a4a79627f3e658c0c2b1e3166f56713a58e1411b1e3ab1e378962e75",
    "Volumes": null,
    "WorkingDir": "",
    "Entrypoint": null,
    "OnBuild": null,
    "Labels": {}
  },
  "created": "2022-08-09T17:19:53.47374331Z",
  "docker_version": "20.10.12",
  "history": [
    {
      "created": "2022-08-09T17:19:53.274069586Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:2a949686d9886ac7c10582a6c29116fd29d3077d02755e87e111870d63607725 in / "
    },
    {
      "created": "2022-08-09T17:19:53.47374331Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD [\"/bin/sh\"]",
      "empty_layer": true
    }
  ],
  "os": "linux",
  "rootfs": {
    "type": "layers",
    "diff_ids": [
      "sha256:994393dc58e7931862558d06e46aa2bb17487044f670f310dffe1d24e4d1eec7"
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that everything is content addressable in the registry, so the sha256sum of the manifest and blob is it's address:

```
$ regctl manifest get \
  localhost:5000/library/alpine@sha256:1304f174557314a7ed9eddb4eab12fed12cb0cd9809e4c28f29af86979a3c870 \
  --format body | sha256sum
1304f174557314a7ed9eddb4eab12fed12cb0cd9809e4c28f29af86979a3c870  -

$ regctl blob get localhost:5000/library/alpine \
  sha256:9c6f0724472873bb50a2ae67a9e7adcb57673a183cea8b06eb778dca859181b5 \
  | sha256sum
9c6f0724472873bb50a2ae67a9e7adcb57673a183cea8b06eb778dca859181b5  -
```

And since the config digest is part of the image manifest, you cannot change that config without changing the config digest and the manifest digest that points to that config. The manifest digest is what you see when you pull an image. The config digest happens to show up when you inspect the image in docker