# Image digest disappears on the `docker images` command when requesting a specific tag

Tags: docker

Good day to all,

I'm trying to get an image digest of a local image to track changes. I can get digests here:

```
$ docker images my/image --digests
REPOSITORY TAG                 DIGEST                                                                    IMAGE ID     CREATED             SIZE
my/image   commit-ec30af3      sha256:5952c64d6851381c2cbc1d16f6092e6718aa1bafe82daab661836010ad59e0db   9020181be91c        8 days ago          265MB
my/image   latest              sha256:5952c64d6851381c2cbc1d16f6092e6718aa1bafe82daab661836010ad59e0db   9020181be91c        8 days ago          265MB
my/image   <none>              sha256:1a886243d70276b9e6df04f4a7d728b95f6a31de763f2b227ff9d6d689ef883c   ff3cc9ff736f        9 days ago          265MB
my/image   <none>              sha256:67f73eedc4ad23a75fc6d769dac74ad358d02a61845b0f1412d4228d21c50c9b   31075b42d215        9 days ago          265MB
my/image   tag-initial         sha256:2a30d97f533a019d91bf333db38d5769508d569c5b7897a9c6f56add14f1f49c   cab098bbb99e        9 days ago          265MB
```

But if I'm trying to read only a specific image tag that I'm tracking changes digest disappears:

```
$ docker images my/image:latest --digests
REPOSITORY TAG                 DIGEST              IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
my/image   latest              <none>              9020181be91c        8 days ago          265MB
```

The same for other tags. No pushes or pulls are made between these two output examples. Images were pushed to the remote repository. I'm checking digests only for images 100% pushed to the remote repo.

I've checked this topic: [Why doesn't my newly-created docker have a digest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811230) but the difference is that digests in that topic were missing even when listing all images. In my case digest exists when listing multiple images and disappears when listing only a specific tag. Also, images were pushed to the remote repo before executing the above commands.

Why it's happening and how to get a digest of a specific tag?

Comment: @GinoMempin As you can see, the `latest`-tagged image has a digest when listed with other images. The question is why this digest isn't printed when only this specific tag is requested?

Comment: It's a bug https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/728